# ArrayAdapter default position by object?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to display a custom list adapter of objects using `parse.com`. I have managed to show all the objects in the list view by `ascending order`. However, I wonder if its possible to put certain object on the top of the screen each time the list is create, and user is still able to `scroll` around?

**Adapter Code**:

```
public class Customer_list_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> {
protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseUser> mCustomers;

public Customer_list_adapter(Context context, List<ParseUser>customers){
    super(context, R.layout.customer_list_layout, customers);
    mContext=context;
    mCustomers=customers;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
    convertView= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.customer_list_layout,null);

    holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.numberLabel=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Number_list_view);
    holder.nameLabel=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name_List_View);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    ParseUser  customer=mCustomers.get(position);
    holder.nameLabel.setText(customer.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_REAL_NAME));
      holder.numberLabel.setText(String.valueOf(customer.getInt(ParseConstants.KEY_SHOP_BUZZ)));
    return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView numberLabel, nameLabel;

}
public void refill(List<ParseUser> customer) {
    mCustomers.clear();
    mCustomers.addAll(customer);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you know the position that the objects are in the array adapter(you should, you created the array adapter), from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html, i would just get the item(getPosition(T item)), call remove(T object) with the same object to remove it from the array adapter, and call insert (T object, int index) with index 0

Comment: I do not know the object position in the array because the array kept updating. for example: if i would like an list of objects and every time i click an button the next coming object move to the top of the screen.

Comment: use onitemclicklistener to see which one was clicked, then manipulate the original list

Comment: hi, is there anyway i can manipulate the list by doing so? i really want the list to keep in the same order just display differently?